# SPARQL Query fails in Ruby-RDF/sparql-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rdf, sparql

The example code:

```
gem 'sparql-client', '~> 1.1.2'
require 'sparql/client'

sparql = SPARQL::Client.new("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
# ASK WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
result = sparql.ask.whether([:s, :p, :o]).true?
```

from the github repo [here](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql-client) gives the following error:

```
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/reader.rb:410:in `fail_subject': ERROR [line 1] Expected subject (found: "{  \"head\": { \"link\": [] }, \"boolean\": true}") (RDF::ReaderError)
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/ntriples/reader.rb:210:in `block in read_triple'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/ntriples/reader.rb:204:in `loop'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/ntriples/reader.rb:204:in `read_triple'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/reader.rb:391:in `read_statement'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/reader.rb:308:in `block in each_statement'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/reader.rb:308:in `loop'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/reader.rb:308:in `each_statement'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/util/aliasing.rb:46:in `block in alias_method'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/mixin/countable.rb:12:in `empty?'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sparql-client-1.1.2/lib/sparql/client/query.rb:268:in `true?'
from /home/USER/tutorial_workspace/sentiment_dev/sparql_query.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Someone got an idea to fix it?

Comment: I'd guess that sparql.ask is performing an ASK query, so you're getting a boolean result, but the client library is trying to parse it as RDF.  This seems consistent with having found `"{  \"head\": { \"link\": [] }, \"boolean\": true}"`.

Comment: It looks like this has already been reported as an issue on the github issue tracker: https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql-client/issues/51 .

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the gravatars were the same after I posted my comment.  It's still a useful comment though, because other users with this problem will still find the bug report.  It's often good practice to provide a link to the bug/issue report if you file one.  In this case, it sounds like the problem has been diagnosed there (I saw a few comments on the issue).